# Matching and printing perl files

Tags: regex, perl

I have a large file (lets say File A) and I am wanting to pull certain lines of data from it in perl. 
An example entry my be as follows.. It would always be 10 points of data and the entries are 5-6 alphanumeric characters long with a : on the end. A line could have more than one entry on it, but `\W+` covers the space in between.

```
.... 
....
LookupReferences: {
  12V0E:
  24983:
  384KJ:
  48743X:
  52V0E:
  64983:
  784KJ:
  88743X:
  94983:
  1084KJ:
}
```

I would want that to look like the following entry that i can load elsewhere.

```
References,12V0E,24983,384KJ,48743X,52V0E,64983,784KJ,88743X,94983,1084KJ
```

I was reading somewhere about forcing the entire page into an array, but any help here is really appreciated as I have been messing around with it and have not really used any perl in 10 years, so could be classed again as an absolute beginner.

Comment: How big exactly is your *“large file”*? Does the closing brace always appear on its own on a line? Is there anything else in the file other than `LookupReferences` blocks?

Comment: It is about 12-15,000 lines, not very large like a million+, but large enough. There are potentially special characters and sometimes the closing brace is on the same line.

Also.. the requirement for the data at the end is the key as I want to print the entire line to the end of another variable, for each entry that there is, so ideally i would just add each grouping to the end of a current variable. 

So for example. 

$data = "Test Results ABC"
would become.
$data = "Test Results ABC,References,12V0E,24983,384KJ,48743X,52V0E,64983,784KJ,88743X,94983,1084KJ";

Answer (score 1):

I quite like the range operator for this job.

E.g.

```
while ( <$file_handle> ) {
     if ( m/LookupReferences/ .. /\}/ ) {
           print;
     }
}
```

(Instead of `print` you may want to process and concatenate or otherwise push into an array).

I'm not so keen about forcing the whole file into an array, because it's not very efficient when you're looking at larger files.

But if you want to do that, it's as simple as:

```
my @file = <$filehandle>;
```

Following on from comments: As you're trying to reformat it, you can do something like:

```
my @references; 
while ( <$file_handle> ) {
     if ( m/LookupReferences/ .. /\}/ ) {
           my ( $value ) = ( m/\s*(\w+):/ );
           if ( defined $value ) { push ( @references, $value )  }; 
     }
}

print join ( ",", "References", @references ),"\n";
```

Comment: Thank you that is getting me the data very well, but it is keeping it in the stanza format, not in the format I need of all entries on the one line.

Comment: Edited with something like an example of what might do the trick.